# All contents of .Nuget/packages folder were deleted after using Ashampoo WinOptimize

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, nuget

In visual studio 2017,I can't debug any application and create new .Net Core projects.
All references were deleted.

Answer (score 0):

> All contents of .Nuget/packages folder were deleted after using Ashampoo WinOptimize

Those packages in the `.Nuget/packages` folder are the cache of the NuGet package. They will be restored when you create or build the `.Net Core` projects.

When you create or build a new `.Net Core` project, you will find that Visual Studio is restoring the package in the status bar at the bottom of the Visual Studio. For example, when you create a new ASP.NET core web App:

[image]

Package restore completed after a while:

[image]

Those packages were restored in the folder `.Nuget/packages`.

So, to restore those packages, **first**, you should make sure the package source `nuget.org` is available (Tools->Options->NuGet Package Manager->Package Sources):

[image]

**Second**, make sure the checkbox `Allow NuGet to download missing packages` is checked:

[image]

Then when you create or build the project, Visual Studio will automatically restore those packages to the `.Nuget/packages`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't work. Projects build well, and packages were restored , but they don't debug and run correctly.

Comment: @AminShirzai, If they do not debug and run correctly, what is the error and it should not be related to nuget, you need update the tags.